# How to remove content using LFS from bitbucket repo

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a git repo on bitbucket.  Recently I added a large file using LFS.  After that I keep on having problem cloning from my repo.  The following is the error message I get:

```
Bitbucket cannot execute 'git-lfs-authenticate [XXX] download'. The command is not supported as entered.

Ensure you are using a supported SCM, check the syntax and try again.: exit status 1
```

I then realize my bitbucket account does not support LFS.
I am ok to just remove the LFS file and recommit it as regular file.  But with the above error I can no longer clone my repo.  How can I fix my repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the file on the website. You should be able to use the source browser to find the file, click on it, and then in the little dropdown menu on the right next to where it says "Edit", there should be a delete option. That should let you create a commit through the website that deletes that file.

If you have trouble with this, I'd highly recommend sending an email to support@bitbucket.org. That will get you in contact with their support team, and they will be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is related to the following issue reported by Atlassian:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-articles/Git-LFS-v3-0-1-includes-backwards-incompatible-changes-with/ba-p/1819819

You could downgrade the git-lfs client to side step it.